# python 3.10.5 asyncio RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def http_request(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def get_results(tasks):
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return result

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [http_request(f"https://httpbin.org/delay/1?seq={x}", session) for x in range(3)]
        return await get_results(tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(main(), debug=False)
    for x in results:
        print(x)
```

I try to use python coroutine module aiohttp to get network request result, but the following exception is thrown：

Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.**del** at 0x000001B9B9886950>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in **del**
self.close()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
self._check_closed()
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

python version is 3.10.5
aiohttp  version 3.8.1

how can i solve it? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aiohttp documentation describes this situation in [graceful-shutdown](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#graceful-shutdown). Inserting the following (on windows) clears the error for me.

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [http_request(f"https://httpbin.org/delay/1?seq={x}", session) for x in range(3)]
        res = await get_results(tasks)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(main())
    for x in results:
        print(x)
```

Alternatively use the last of the solutions posted [Issue #1925](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/1925). Although I accept these messages are warnings - not debug messages - and ignore them. Simpler.

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [http_request(f"https://httpbin.org/delay/1?seq={x}", session) for x in range(3)]
        for x in await get_results(tasks):
            print(x)
        ce = create_aiohttp_closed_event(session)
    await ce.wait()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Python's coroutine is really difficult to use,  goroutine is easy to use